# Converting Kinect depth map to RGB ground truth depth maps

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have an RGB image and its corresponding Kinect depth map which is in black and white. I need to convert the black and white depth map to an RGB depth map. What is the best way to proceed with this?

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is an RGB depth map? RGB refers to an image in the form of Red, Green, and Blue channels. Depth is a single channel of information, so for visualization it typically maps onto a black and white image. Are you instead looking for a heatmap representation? A heatmap is a graphical representation of values using colour instead of intensity ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map) has an overview of them). Depending on which programming language you are using, there are usually several options for standard colour schemes for heatmaps.

In Python you can plot a 2D array as a heatmap using the [imshow()](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) function from matplotlib.pyplot by specifying the `cmap` parameter. For example, you might find `cmap='hot'` or `cmap='plasma'` gives you the output you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong terminology used. I am afraid I don't exactly know the terminology I am looking for, but what I need to create is a map which shows different colors for different depths in the image. What I have are the RGB images and their corresponding black and white depth maps. I am using Python programming language. Can you kindly guide me on how to proceed?

Comment: Yes, this definitely sounds like you are looking for a heatmap. I have edited my answer to reflect this updated information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It was very helpful. This is what I have been looking for!